# App crashes when calling AsyncTask from GCMIntentService

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to run an AsyncTask from GCMBaseIntentService, but however the app crashes when I do it.
The moving point is that I want to use the context from MainActivity to let my AsyncTask work (showing ProgressDialog <-- needs context). When I do the same from MainActivity it works, but when I try to call AsyncTask from GCMIntentService, no ProgressDialog is shown - how can I do that?
Or is there any other way to call AsyncTask that it work?

I want to call AsyncTask everytime when a Message is arrive (onMessage())
For weeks I am trying to solve that problem, still got no hint

Here are parts of my code:

MainActivity.java

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    public static Context getAppContext() {
            return MainActivity.mContext;
        }
```

onCreate (MainActivity.java)

```
MainActivity.mContext = MainActivity.this;
```

My AsyncTask:

```
public class AsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

    Context mContext;


    public AsyncTask(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;

    }
```

GCMIntentService onMessage():

```
AsyncTask doStuff= new AsyncTask(MainActivity.getAppContext());
        doStuff.execute();
```

EDIT:

When I use MainActivity.getAppContext() as context in GCM

AsyncTask does run, does all stuff, like "  DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(mContext);"
it does all db stuff, i can see that also in log, but there are a lot of warning.
 for example in AsyncTask the ProgressDialog is not shown:

```
  pDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
            pDialog.setMessage("blablabla");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
          pDialog.show();
```

When I use "this" instead of "MainActivity.getAppContext()"

this Log appear:

```
 AndroidRuntime(3029): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
 AndroidRuntime(3029):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:768)
 AndroidRuntime(3029):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:278)
 AndroidRuntime(3029):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
 AndroidRuntime(3029):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:289)
 AndroidRuntime(3029):  at com.test.app.AsyncTask.onPreExecute(AsyncTask.java:98)
 AndroidRuntime(3029):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
 AndroidRuntime(3029):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
 AndroidRuntime(3029):  at com.test.app.GCMIntentService.onMessage(GCMIntentService.java:62)
 AndroidRuntime(3029):  at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:223)
 AndroidRuntime(3029):  at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
 AndroidRuntime(3029):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 AndroidRuntime(3029):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 AndroidRuntime(3029):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: if you are in a service you get context from using `this` not context from your MainActivity that may or may not be available

Comment: but when I use this it does work :S

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open a dialog from a service, i think the best thing to do is launch an activity with transparent background and launch the dialog from there.
You can start an activity from a `Service`

Comment: Do you have any example or Template How İ have to do it

Comment: I think I understand you -

1 - Creating a an Extra Activity
2- Including my AsyncTak into that Extra Actitivy
3 - Starting my Extra Activity when Message arrives in my Service, which runs the AsyncTask?

Comment: @user3650191 depends what do you want to do into your `AsyncTask`

Comment: showing pDialog while making operation in sqlite like   DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(mContext);
                        db.updatelist(list); @TheRedFox

Comment: my idea is that i have a mainActivity, where my layout is shown, every thing else should be without layout - done in background, like doin stuff when message arrives : like doin sql operation or showing dialogs

Comment: your Idea worked... 

1) When a message arrives another activity is getting started, which includes an AsyncTask which do my job like ProgressDialog -(it works)
2) onPosteExecute: When the job is done, it startes my MainActivity...

It's not the best solution i wished, but it works... I think I have to use a layout for the new activity where is standing "wait: updating or something like that^^